# JavaScript not executing in .NET WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, webbrowser-control

Two friends of mine have tested a project I have been working on which relies on the use of the WebBrowser control, and have managed to come across a constant scenario in which the WebBrowser control is unable to execute any JavaScript on the contained web page.

For the sake of narrowing it down I created a new Windows Forms project that contains only a WebBrowser control, and tries to navigate to the following page: http://javatester.org/javascript.html

The result on my friends computer was the below (click to enlarge):

[image: Control render]

As you can see, it doesn't render ANYTHING when trying to call the JS specific code, alternatively if you view it in a web browser with JS disabled or enabled, you'll see something.

He exported his registry keys that contain the setting for JavaScript being enabled (see https://gist.github.com/4699943) and the value for 1400 in each of the keys matches the same settings I use, and when I run the program I have no issue.

The code for the entire test project is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://javatester.org/javascript.html");
        }
    }
}
```

If a new project is created using this code that targets the 4.5 framework (either on my machine or his) it works, however if one is created using 4.0 or lower the above result occurs. I'm not sure if this is a coincidence or if it is indeed something to do with the problem / solution.

It should be noted that if he navigates to this page in Internet Explorer there are no issues, it detects that JavaScript is enabled, this problem solely resides in this test application and the main project that it is a part of.

Any help would be appreciated, I've spent a good two months trying to figure this out and still can't.

Comment: I don't believe that the framework version should be an issue. I've done projects in 3.5 that JavaScript works fine on.  I do know that because of other issues I've had with the standard `WebBrowser` control I've moved a lot of my projects to use WebKit.net (WebKit is the layout engine of Chrome and Safari). It's a great tool and they've really tried to make it similar to the standard control. If I were you I'd at least check it out. [WebKit.net](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net)

Comment: @LeonNewswanger - This is slightly off topic, but: I have previously looked in to switching to WebKit, however some of the future requirements of the project are that we can call back into the assembly from JavaScript using the ObjectForScripting property, and I've never been able to find such a thing in WebKit; have you ever come across this in WebKit?

Comment: I've honestly never looked, sorry. I realize it isn't really an answer to you question. That's why I posted it as a comment, and as I was unaware of your other requirements, I thought it may be something that could help you resolve your issue.

Comment: There have been other things in the past with WebKit that I've had to delve into the interop itself to find however, because a big part of the WebKit.net packages are just wrapper classes basically.

Comment: Perhaps older framework versions use older webbrowser dlls which then use older IE dlls which do not support newer javascript functions.

Comment: @HanletEscaño we have tested with JavaScript containing just basic stuff such as alerts and functions that return a fixed boolean value, none seem to work though.

Comment: Do both computers have the latest IE installed? I know it may seem silly, but believe me, I have had problems in the past using WebBrowser and old IE version.

Comment: @HanletEscaño - yes, both have IE9

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333973/how-to-get-rendered-html-processed-by-javascript-in-webbrowser-control

Comment: The meta tag solution may be of interest.  IE7 be default

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control

Answer (score 0):

From my tests WebBrowser with .NET 4 reports a web browser agent string of IE 7.0.  Therefore, check your JavaScript works correctly in IE7 first.

Answer (score -1):

The scripts do not load if you are using the webbrowser control.Document Text property. It perfectly fine with the Navigate method. I need the document text property to work as i get html from third party. The same html content work perfectly fine if i create an html file out of it and open it in the regular IE browser. The webbrowser control is buggy.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this answer, or provide more explanation or documentation?