# HTML of an MVC view along with plotly graphs embedded into the view

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, plotly

We are working on a MVC application which uses plotly for drawing graphs in the MVC view. Plotly's general behavior is to draw graphs in browser environment based on the type of graph selected and the data provided. These graphs are part of MVC views and partial views accordingly. Plotly adds the DOM of the graph only after the base layout of the page is loaded.

Next, we have a requirement to create a sample application (not web, could be a .net console app) which is expected to get the MVC view (HTML) rendered along with plotly graphs without opening the existing MVC web application.

We tried calling the existing MVC action method passing appropriate parameters from the console app to get output HTML as a view. We receive the view but the issue is that the plotly has not rendered the required HTML DOM inside the base HTML. Hence, currently we are receiving the HTML DOM without plotly being rendered. But, we need the HTML DOM of the entire web page with plotly rendered i.e. along with SVG elements embedded into the HTML DOM.

Hence, not sure on how to proceed in this.
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the following, looks like they are doing something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333973/how-to-get-rendered-html-processed-by-javascript-in-webbrowser-control  , not a console app though.