# Download html doesnt retrieve dynamically generated elements

Tags: c#, html, json, download

For documentation purposes I need the html of each "...Controller" element on the following website :
https://apipivotdev.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index.

This doesn't work :

```
  string html;
  using (var wc = new WebClient())
  html= wc.DownloadString(url);
```

because that will only render a few divs at the top of the document.
Parsing the underlying json and merging it with html would be too timeconsuming and again, I just need the html.

Question: How would I get the **complete** webpage in C# ?

Comment: The page is complete, it has not been executed and doesn't has dynamic data... If you want the data post-execution use a WebBrowser control, wait to load all the data and then export the DOM

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333973/how-to-get-rendered-html-processed-by-javascript-in-webbrowser-control

Comment: I tried the example , but it doesn't work. Even in the webbrowser control, the page displays only a few html elements. Thanks anyway