# How to get a rendered HTML (Processed by Javascript) C#

Tags: javascript, c#, linux, performance, web-crawler

I want to receive a rendered HTML.
At the moment I am using the namespace "EO.WebBrowser" and it works for this purpose.
But I always get a reminder to use a license (The license is only for commercial purposes)

So my question is: "Is there a better way without using forms?"

[Reference to the same question by using forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333973/how-to-get-rendered-html-processed-by-javascript-in-webbrowser-control)

My current code:

```
    internal static string GetHtml(string url)
{
  ThreadRunner runner = new ThreadRunner();

  WebView view = runner.CreateWebView();

  runner.Send(() =>
  {
    view.LoadUrlAndWait(url);
  });

  return view.GetHtml();
}
```

It will be a linux service for my raspberry pi (Rasbian OS).

Comment: Did you try selenium or playwright?

Comment: No, never heard of. I will look for those libraries. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @DavidMrochen Could you solve it?